# Combining arrays in powershell gives System.Object[] in output?

Tags: string, powershell, join

I'm looping through some files and want to prepend the filename to an existing file. 
I thought I'd got stuff going ok, but by the second time around the loop, I lose the existing end of the file, and get System.Object[] instead of the former contents.

A simple example here shows roughly what I'm doing to prepend the information, and replicates the outcome (which I don't want!).

```
$a = "1","2","3"
$b = "test"
$c = -join $b,$a
# At this point, $c is as I expect; it has added $b to the start of the list.
$a = $c
$c = -join $b,$a
# This time, when I try to add $b to the front of $a, it correctly adds the new line, and the second line is also correct, but then it dumps the object properties of the remaining lines (or something?)
```

The output is shown below

```
 test
 test


Length         : 3
LongLength     : 3
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {1, 2, 3}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
Count          : 3
```

If you're writing this to a file using set-content, then it writes the object properties as System.Object[], which isn't what I want!

Thanks

Update:
As per the comment on this original post, the solution I'm looking for is to use $a = (,$b)+$a.
This has the effect of prepending the string in $b to the start of the array of strings stored in $a.

Comment: Unary `-join` is string concatenation operator. Unary `-join` have higher precedence than binary comma. Thus `-join $b,$a` is `(-join $b),$a`.

Comment: P.S. `(,$b)+$a`

Comment: Dude your (,$b)+$a works... why don't you write is as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need some clarification here:

```
$a = "1","2","3"
$b = "test"
$c = -join $b,$a
```

does not create an array `$c` containing

```
'test', '1', '2', '3'
```

instead `$c`looks like this:

```
'test', ('1', '2', '3')
```

What I think you wanted to do is:

```
$c = $b , $a
```

which results in

```
'test', '1', '2', '3'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I went away from using + for the strings because it doesn't do what I want. I need the output to be "test";"1";"2";"3" (where ; represents a new line), but instead it outputs test1 2 3

Comment: Well I didn't realise you could use a comma as well! There's about 15 ways to join strings, it seems. Unfortunately your method doesn't work for this problem. Please try the following (where ; is a line break): $a = "1","2","3"; $b = "test"; $a = $b,$a; $a = $b,$a; #You will see that $a contains Object Properties

Comment: That is an display issue from powershell itself.

Comment: The question is now more: What do you want to do? Would you update your question with that info?